# Rails: (Simple) model method clarification. What is the "&" before my attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I'm currently going through a tutorial on unit tests. I have two models: `Song` and `Album`.

```
class Song < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :duration_in_seconds
  belongs_to :album
end

class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :artist, :title

  has_many :songs


  def duration
    songs.sum(&:duration_in_seconds)
  end

end
```

This is the test that's supposed to pass:

```
require 'test_helper'

class AlbumTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "should be able to report duration based on combined duration of its songs" do
    album = Album.create
    3.times do
      album.songs.create(:duration_in_seconds => 5)
    end
    assert_equal 15, album.duration
  end
end
```

As you see in the Album model, there is a method called `duration`. I have two questions about that.

1. So we know that Song belongs to Album. If I do a method on an instance of Album, I can just access the songs of that instance in that method directly like that? The method definition looks weird... @album.duration would return @album.songs.sum(&:duration_in_seconds)? Lets say I had this method in my Album method:

`def name_of_album`

`title`

`end`

If I called `@album.name_of_album` would it be the same as `@album.title`?

1. What's with the `&` in the duration method? Is it the same as `songs.sum(:duration_in_seconds)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ampersand is part of Ruby and when it's used in front of a symbol, it converts it to a `Proc`.
See http://railscasts.com/episodes/6-shortcut-blocks-with-symbol-to-proc?view=asciicast for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your first question #1 (your both questions have #1):

All (public) methods defined in your `Class Album` can be used by an instance of that class like `@album.your_method` (private and protected methods by `@album.send(:your_private_or_protected_method)`).

So yes, `@album.name_of_album` would give the same result as `@album.title` in your example.

If I understand your question correct, and that is really your question I suggest that you study Ruby a bit.

Your second question is already answered, but I add this anyway.

```
songs.sum(&:duration_in_seconds)
```

is the same as e.g.

```
songs.sum { |song| song.duration_in_seconds }
```